# Trying to get std::function work with void* parameter

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a generic Messenger callback Class implemented. It is basically a map of string to a vector of generic member functions.

```
std::map<Message, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> _receivers;
```

The class has static functions that basically allows you to register an enum Message to a member function like this:

```
Messenger::GetInstance()->RegisterObserver(Message::QUIT, std::bind(&System::OnQuit, this));
```

Then whenever the message is broadcast somewhere, the callback happens.

```
Messenger::GetInstance()->Broadcast(Message::QUIT);
```

The implementation is as follows.

```
class Messenger
{
public:

    template <typename Receiver>
    void RegisterObserver(Message msg, Receiver&& receiver)
    {
       _receivers[msg].push_back(std::forward<Receiver>(receiver));
    }

    static Messenger* GetInstance();

    void Broadcast(Message msg) const
    {
        for (const auto& obs : _receivers.at(msg)) obs();
    }

    void Broadcast(Message msg, void* param) const;
    {
        for (const auto& obs : _receivers.at(msg)) obs(param); // Does NOT work
    }   

    ~Messenger();

private:
    Messenger() { };

    std::map<Message, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> _receivers;
    static Messenger* _instance;
};
```

The implementation works well with no parameters.

Now I also need this to work with void* parameter so that I can also pass anything along with the broadcast if I need to so that it gets called in the callback.

This is what I want to achieve.

```
Messenger::GetInstance()->Broadcast(Message::QUIT, *param);
```

Any advice or solution is very appreciated. This will help me keep my design sane.

I tried changing map to --

```
std::map<Message, std::list<std::function<void(void*)>>> _receivers;
```

and then changing the call signatures to **void CallbackName(void* param)**. However I get error

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

Probably because of this:

```
Messenger::GetInstance()->RegisterObserver(Message::QUIT, std::bind(&System::OnQuit, this));
```

Comment: Dud you at least try adapting your function signature to handle that parameter? Where did you get stuck doing that?

Comment: You may create 2 `std::map`, one for `std::function<void()>` and the other for `std::function<void(void*)>`.

Comment: Mat: Tried that got error mentioned above.

Comment: Jarod42: How will the Register function work in that case ?

Comment: What parameters does `System::OnQuit()` take in the case where it gives the error?

Comment: System::OnQuit(void* param) is the causing issue it seems.

Comment: Basically I want to create a map of string to generic member function pointers that can also take void* arguments. The actual parameter will however will be passed on at the time the map is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create 2 maps, and use 2 register methods.
If you want the same name, you may use SFINAE as the following: [Live example](https://ideone.com/iPeg6W)

```
class Messenger
{
public:
    template <typename Receiver>
    auto RegisterObserver(Message msg, Receiver&& receiver) -> decltype(receiver(), void())
    {
        _receivers0[msg].push_back(std::forward<Receiver>(receiver));
    }

    template <typename Receiver>
    auto RegisterObserver(Message msg, Receiver&& receiver) -> decltype(receiver(nullptr), void())
    {
        _receivers1[msg].push_back(std::forward<Receiver>(receiver));
    }

    // Others methods

private:

    std::map<Message, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> _receivers0;
    std::map<Message, std::vector<std::function<void(void*)>>> _receivers1;
};
```

Comment: Fantastic Jarod42. This is absolutely what I wanted to achieve. :) 
If you can add the methods for Unregistering the observers too for the 2 maps, that would make it perfect!